# Open SSL Rand function

Tags: c++

I am fairly new to programming with open ssl. Here is a code snippet which should generate a random number and later on get converted to hexa decimal format.
The code is getting compiled, however when I run the file I am getting Segmentation Error: Core Dumped message.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<openssl/aes.h>
#include<openssl/bn.h>
#include<openssl/rand.h>
using namespace std;
int  main()
{
    int i;
    void *buf;
    long *p;
    *p=67563;
    buf=p;
    RAND_seed(buf,9);
    BIGNUM *rnd
    i= BN_rand( *rnd, 128,0,0);
    BN_bn2hex(rnd);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have uninitialized pointers in your code! They will most probabely point to invalid memory, where you cannot write to, causing the Segmentation Faults.

The variables of concern are `p` and `rnd`:

```
long *p;     // p is not initialized, pointing to invalid memory
*p = 67563;  // Writing to invalid memory => SEGFAULT
```

Try this instead:

```
int i;
void *buf;

long p;    // NO POINTER!
p=67563;

buf=&p;   // Let buf point to where p is (valid address on stack)
RAND_seed(buf,9);

BIGNUM rnd;  // NO POINTER!
i= BN_rand( &rnd, 128,0,0);  // Pass pointer to rnd to BN_rand

BN_bn2hex(&rnd); // Pass pointer to rnd to BN_bn2hex
```